# Why GNU make ignores SIGINT, but then doesn't execute following commands?

Tags: makefile

I want make to execute the command on line 92 (killall) even when preceding command on line 91 (gdb) was stopped with SIGINT (by Ctrl+C):

```
 88 debug:                                                                                                                                                                                     
 89     make all                                                                                                                                                                               
 90     make flash                                                                                                                                                                             
 91     -$(GDB) $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(GDBCOMMANDS)                                                                                                                                                
 92     killall openocd
```

However, even though make prints information about ignoring the interrupt, it still does not run killall afterwards:

```
make: [Makefile:91: debug] Interrupt (ignored)
```

All works as expected when I quit the GDB without SIGINT - killall is executed.

Why make doesn't try to execute killall in the scenario above?
How do I make it work?

You can test the problem yourself with this Makefile (echo won't be executed if you press CTRL+C in man window before quitting, but it will if work you simply exit by 'q'):

```
all:
    -man man                                                                                                                                                                                   
    echo 'It worked!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ^C is being caught by make as well (when you run ^C all processes in the terminal's process group receive the signal) and make is exiting (after cleaning up) so it never tries to run any more commands, just as if you'd entered ^C during the make process.

The only way to avoid this would be to ensure that make didn't receive the SIGINT at all, and the only way to do that is to change the process group.  I'm not sure if there's any handy utility that will do that for you.

My recommendation is to not try to invoke debuggers or other interactive programs from inside a make recipe.  It's not designed for that.  In addition to issues above, you'll find that if you try to run with parallel builds enabled then, since only one process can get stdin from the terminal, a random one will be chosen to get a "real" stdin and the others will have their stdin closed or read from /dev/null or something.

Instead, why not just create a shell script to do the debugging, which will run the make commands you want then invoke gdb.  This shell script can use `trap` to catch SIGINT and ignore it, to ensure it always runs the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer makes a good point about make, but to make a solution work only in make, you could make use of [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) to do the `trap`.

1. When I tested your example I found that `man` appears to ignore `SIGINT` on its own so it's not really the best test case
2. [Avoid using recursion](https://web.archive.org/web/20070205051133/http://members.canb.auug.org.au/%7Emillerp/rmch/recu-make-cons-harm.html) when you can easily use prerequisites `debug: all flash` (but remember the caveat about parallelism)
3. If you do use `.ONESHELL`, it's wise to also choose `.SHELLFLAGS` appropriately otherwise your recipes will not behave the way you are used to.
4. I noticed you're killing all openocd instances, you might want to think of a more controlled method, ie: write a separate script as was suggested.

EDIT: As pointed out in comments, don't expect other targets to be built after this one.

```
.ONESHELL:
# The flag -e mimics the traditional behaviour of exiting as soon as any command fails
.SHELLFLAGS := -e -c 

debug: all flash      
     trap 'true' INT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     $(GDB) $(PROJ_NAME).elf $(GDBCOMMANDS) || error=$$?                                                                                                                                               
     killall openocd  # All of them?
     exit $${error}
```

Comment: Even though the `killall` may be executed after the SIGINT is received in this case, that will not prevent `make` itself from receiving the signal, too, so that it terminates instead of building any other targets.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's correct. Given the target looks a lot like something you would run manually in a shell only after building everything (`all`), the poster might be willing to deal with that limitation.